# error when installing pandas package: no module named numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a big solutions with multiple projects inside. I use `virtualenv` for that.
So for one of my projects in solution I already install the stuff I need, including `numpy` and `pandas`

but when I I executing something like that:

```
cd ../project2
sudo python setup.py develop
```

It fails installing `pandas` package and show the error

```
ImportError: no module named numpy
```

But if I run something like that right after

```
python
import numpy
numpy.version.version
import pandas
pandas.version.version
```

it resolve this code absolutely correctly and show me the versions of packages installed.

**So what it the problem there and how could I resolve it to being able to install project dependencies?**

OS: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, Python 2.7.3

---

`python -msite` output

```
sys.path = [
    '/home/user1/code/myproject/project2',
    '/home/user1/code/myproject/project1/src',
    '/home/user1/code/myproject/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo-2.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
    '/home/user1/code/myproject/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg',
    '/home/user1/code/myproject/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
    '/home/user1/code/myproject/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.13.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
    '/home/user1/code/myproject/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy-0.13.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
    '/home/user1/code/myproject/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk-2.0.4-py2.7.egg',
    '/home/user1/code/myproject/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MarkupSafe-0.19-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
    '/home/user1/code/myproject/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytz-2014.1-py2.7.egg',
    '/home/user1/code/myproject/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_dateutil-2.2-py2.7.egg',
    '/home/user1/code/myproject/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyYAML-3.10-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
    '/home/user1/code/myproject/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six-1.6.1-py2.7.egg',
    '/home/user1/code/myproject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo-2.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
    '/home/user1/code/myproject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg',
    '/home/user1/code/myproject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
    '/home/user1/code/myproject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.13.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
    '/home/user1/code/myproject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy-0.13.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
    '/home/user1/code/myproject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk-2.0.4-py2.7.egg',
    '/home/user1/code/myproject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MarkupSafe-0.19-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
    '/home/user1/code/myproject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytz-2014.1-py2.7.egg',
    '/home/user1/code/myproject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_dateutil-2.2-py2.7.egg',
    '/home/user1/code/myproject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyYAML-3.10-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
    '/home/user1/code/myproject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six-1.6.1-py2.7.egg',
    '/home/user1/code/myproject/venv/lib/python2.7',
    '/home/user1/code/myproject/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
    '/home/user1/code/myproject/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
    '/home/user1/code/myproject/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
    '/home/user1/code/myproject/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
    '/home/user1/code/myproject/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
    '/home/user1/code/myproject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/home/user1/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/home/user1/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages' (exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: False
```

---

output of `sudo python -msite`

```
sys.path = [
    '/home/user1/code/myproject/project2',
    '/home/user1/code/myproject/project1/src',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo-2.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg',
    '/home/user1/code/myproject/project_flask/src',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk-2.0.4-py2.7.egg',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy-2.2-py2.7.egg',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_twitter-0.8.2-py2.7.egg',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lamson-1.1-py2.7.egg',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery-3.1.9-py2.7.egg',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyYAML-3.10-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine-0.7.9-py2.7.egg',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/multiprocessing-2.6.2.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask_WTF-0.5.2-py2.7.egg',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask_Mail-0.6.1-py2.7.egg',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask-0.7.2-py2.7.egg',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Werkzeug-0.8.1-py2.7.egg',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/WTForms-0.6.3-py2.7.egg',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2-1.5.211-py2.7.egg',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_daemon-1.6-py2.7.egg',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose-1.3.1-py2.7.egg',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mock-1.0.1-py2.7.egg',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu-3.0.14-py2.7.egg',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/billiard-3.3.0.16-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytz-2014.1-py2.7.egg',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blinker-1.3-py2.7.egg',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol',
]
USER_BASE: '/home/user1/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/home/user1/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

Comment: Please post the output of `python -msite` and `sudo python -msite`.

Comment: `virtualenv --system-site-packages` saves you from installing NumPy and SciPy every time (and potentially getting a suboptimal build).

Comment: @SvenMarnach Wow, That's fantastic. I just run command without sudo and it's work. Thanks a lot. Could you provide it as an answer which will allow me accept it. I also will be very appreciate if you provide very basic notes about differences sudo and non sudo calls, because for current moment I just thinking sudo only run command with wider credentials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As can be seen from the output of `python -msite`, `python` and `sudo python` run Python versions in very different envirnoments. It's no surprise they see diferent modules.  `sudo` usually changes your environment, in particular your `PATH` and `HOME` environment variables, which may lead to either a different PYTHON interpreter being run, or a differemt `user` module being imported.

In general, when installing something inside a virtualenv in your home directory, there is no reason why you would want to use sudo. You should use the pip installation within the virtualenv to install packages.

Answer (score 8):

I recently had this error while trying to update Pandas from version 0.23.1 to 0.24.1.

What solved my problem was to first update pip by executing:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

And then updating the desired library.

Comment: Pip 9.0.3 was installed by default and gave me OP's error. I ran this to install pip 21.3.1. The later version installed pandas correctly. Astonishing.